# How to run the set of commands in windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

`x264-preset` is used in the second command (`Cmd 2`). Is it substitution or?

Cmd 1:

```
x264-preset:
vcodec=libx264
thread_type=slice
slices=1
profile=baseline
level=32
preset=superfast
tune=zerolatency
intra-refresh=1
crf=15
x264-params=vbv-maxrate=5000:vbv-bufsize=1:slice-max-size=1500:keyint=60
```

Cmd 2

```
$ ffmpeg -r 30 -f dshow -i video="devicename" -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -vpre
x264-preset -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:8888
```

When I run the `Cmd 1` it doesn't work. Even with the SET like:

```
x264-preset:
SET vcodec=libx264
SET thread_type=slice
SET slices=1
SET profile=baseline
SET level=32
SET preset=superfast
SET tune=zerolatency
SET intra-refresh=1
SET crf=15
SET x264-params=vbv-maxrate=5000:vbv-bufsize=1:slice-max-size=1500:keyint=60
```

Source:
https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-January/030127.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to execute the contents of a custom [preset file](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Preset-files). To run it as a normal command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f dshow -i video="devicename" -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -vcodec libx264 -thread_type slice -slices 1 -profile:v baseline -level 32 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -intra-refresh 1 -crf 15 -x264-params vbv-maxrate=5000:vbv-bufsize=1:slice-max-size=1500:keyint=60 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:8888
```